# How to catch POST using WSGIREF

Tags: python, wsgi, wsgiref

I am trying to catch POST data from a simple form.

This is the first time I am playing around with WSGIREF and I can't seem to find the correct way to do this.

```
This is the form:
<form action="test" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit"></form>
```

And the function that is obviously missing the right information to catch post:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    """starts the response for the webserver"""
    path = environ[ 'PATH_INFO']
    method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
    if method == 'POST':
        if path.startswith('/test'):
            start_response('200 OK',[('Content-type', 'text/html')])
            return "POST info would go here %s" % post_info
    else:
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html')])
        return form()
```

Comment: What's happening instead of the correct behavior?

I just ran this app with a quick `paster server` and everything seems to work as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be reading responses from the server.

From [nosklo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394465/python-post-data-using-modwsgi) to a similar problem:  "[PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) says [you must read environ['wsgi.input']](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#input-and-error-streams)."

Tested code (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336866/how-to-implement-a-minimal-server-for-ajax-in-python)):

    Caveat: This code is for demonstrative purposes only. 

    Warning: Try to avoid hard-coding paths or filenames.

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    path    = environ['PATH_INFO']
    method  = environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
    if method == 'POST':
        if path.startswith('/test'):
            try:
                request_body_size = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
                request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                request_body = "0"
            try:
                response_body = str(request_body)
            except:
                response_body = "error"
            status = '200 OK'
            headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
            start_response(status, headers)
            return [response_body]
    else:
        response_body = open('test.html').read()
        status = '200 OK'
        headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]
        start_response(status, headers)
        return [response_body]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed! One modification though, was to add [5:] to response_body to avoid the 'size=' part.